# Moving an image through 5000 location does not work in different thread android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation

I want to move my image through approximately 5000 points which draws like orbit of a satellite. I have a button and an image.First, I have added onclicklistener to my button which is:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                //mc.animate().x(points[i].x).y(points[i].y).setDuration(1000);
                mc.setX(points[i].x);
                mc.setY(points[i].y);

            }

        }
    });
```

Then it did not work. I got "*Choreographer(abc): Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread*" in my logcat. After research, i tried to make this work in another thread. My code was like:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
                        final int j = i;
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                System.out.println(j);
                                mc.setX(points[j].x);
                                mc.setY(points[j].y);
                                try {
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }.start();
```

I still cant move the image and get the *"Choreographer(abc): Skipped xx frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread"* in the logcat. I have also  tried "animate" but it did not worked too. What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no sleep or other functionality to make it wait between changing points.  This means you'll run runOnUIThread 5000 times very quickly.  This will cause 5000 messages to be passed to the ui thread's looper.  The UI thread will run through all 5000.  It won't actually draw, because that requires a message that won't get processed until its turn in queue.  Then you'll eventually hit the draw after processing all 5000 messages, by which point the image will be in the last place.

Solution is to decide how fast the animation should go, and add sleeps or waits of some sort to make sure only that many moves are done per second (for example, for 10fps, sleep 100 between each iteration of that loop).  You may also need an invalidate call at the end of your runOnUIThread function, but I can't tell for sure-  depends on the implementation of setX and setY.

Comment: Actually I had tried the sleep but inside the runOnUIThread in the try clause and it did not work. then i said it is not working. but now it is working because i just carried that sleep outside of runOnUIThread. now it is working. What is the difference?

Comment: The difference is what thread you're sleeping on.  You want to sleep on the secondary thread, so that you send messages to the UI thread and redraw every few hundred ms.  If you sleep on the UI thread, you get an even worse version of your original problem.